# Installing wine on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, wine

Well, I wonder if I am doing the right thing. I need to install Wine on 12.04 as its not install by default, and  I had use the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

And

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Was it right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You might want to add `sudo apt-get install winetricks` if you are trying to install wine 1.5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the PPA will let you install the latest wine updated before it is released in the official repository.

According to the [official website](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) wine1.5 is still in beta. So I wouldn't suggest installing it if you need something stable, so I would install wine1.4 instead. Unless you are certain the Windows application you need to run, only works on wine1.5.

So in short I would recommend the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa #This is optional since 1.4 is already available in the official repositories
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.4
```

But in case you are willing to install a beta package, and accept a few crashes every now and then (not saying that crashes WILL happen, but they are possible), then installing `wine1.5` and reporting bugs and crashes is the way to go:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa #This is required since 1.5 is not available in the official repositories
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.4
```

Comment: i had try and i am having and error saying 


E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
ash@ash-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.4
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
ash@ash-System-Product-Name:~$

Comment: @user83467 Do you have any of the following running: `Update Manager`, `Ubuntu Software Center` or `apt-get` in another terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [link](http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/) has given simple steps to install Wine 1.6.2 under Debian 7/6, Ubuntu 14.10/14.04/13.10/13.04/12.10/12.04/11.10 and Linux Mint 17/16/15/14/13 systems

hope these helps  you.

Comment: See this page if you want 1.7:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/wine-1-7-35-support-opengl-core-contexts/

That's the development release (i.e. it's a work-in-progress that may have bugs), if you want to use the latest stable version (i.e. mainstream version, that should be mostly bug-free), see:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/install-wine-1-6-2-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Which version you want to install is based on this line sudo apt-get install wine1.7